# VBS Windows proxy enable

Tags: vbscript

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell, RegLocate

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable"
objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,"0","REG_DWORD"

WScript.Sleep 1000

If "REG_DWORD" = "" then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet\Settings\ProxyEnable Settings\ProxyEnable",1,"REG_DWORD"
else
MsgBox "Proxy alrdy running"
end if
WScript.Quit
```

So my problem is not to get the proxy settings in, I have script for that and it works. The problem is to enable it in IE explorer.

The script runs and don't get an error... so I have hit a wall.

Sorry for bad grammar and English.

Comment: Just to clarify. You have a vbscript running as .vbs, but you want this vbs to work in Visual Basic (.net?) in Internet Explorer on the client's computer? If so [this page may help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289494(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: yes it runs in vbs i believe, all i want it to do is enable proxy server option on a Win 10 machine, IE 11.  i do not really know xD never touched VB or VBS before i tried doing this in PS but didnt get any resault so i am the biggest NOOB in this matter.

Comment: You want to run the script inside of IE, or you want to toggle the proxy setting in IE? I guess I'm not following what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Users use IE as a standard browser, and when they log on to the system the browser should the proxy enabled, its gonna run through GPO as a logon script. so i think i want to toggle the proxy setting in IE.